# Program that counts odd numbers and then prints them

Tags: python

So I have question about my homework.

Program must do:

```
    * Asks from user the number of clients ( not negative int number )
    * Uses while and gets total number of flowers
    * Print final sum to screen.
```

We have text like:
It's womens day and flowershop decided to give flowers to women. But thing is, only odd number gets them. 
So first one gets 1, second one gets nothing, third gets 3 , fifth gets 5 and so on. If you insert 7, then sum of odd numbers is 16 : 1 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 16. If user inserts 8, then sum is also 16 : 1 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 16.
The odd number can't be bigger than number of women.

You have to insert the number of women.

I have done this:

```
women = int(input("Insert number of buyers: "))
i = 1
sum = 0
while i < women:
    i = i + 2
    sum = sum + i
print("Total of flowers is: " + str(women))
```

But it dosent work and my brain is totally out of ideas already :(

Final result must look like this:

```
Insert number of buyers: 7
Total of flowers is : 16
```

Comment: Add `i` to `sum` before your increment `i`. Also, print `sum`.

Comment: why don't you check if `i` is odd or not?

Comment: I agree with Zachi: the intention is probably that you iterate from 1 up to the number of women, and add only for odd numbers. (I'm assuming you've been taught about `if` by this point; if you haven't then something closer to what you're doing is better.)

Comment: Incidentally -- and don't try handing this for your homework, you'll get caught instantly -- you can actually calculate the number of flowers like this: `((women+1)//2)**2` :-).

Comment: This is a very well-written first question. Welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three flaws in your code:

- Incrementing `i` before incrementing `sum` (meaning the first lady gets 3 flowers)
- Using 1 based indices to count the women, but using the wrong loop condition (with `women=7` the loop body will not execute if `i==7`, so it should be `i <= women`)
- Not printing the answer (`sum`) but the input (`women`)

Here is a fixed version:

```
women = int(input("Insert number of buyers: "))
i = 1
sum = 0
while i <= women:
    sum = sum + i
    i = i + 2
print("Total of flowers is: " + str(sum))
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this with a list comprehension:

```
women = int(input("Insert number of buyers: "))
flowers = sum(i for i in range(1, women+1) if i%2 == 1)
print("Total of flowers is:", flowers)
```

Or using `range`'s step parameter:

```
women = int(input("Insert number of buyers: "))
flowers = sum(range(1, women+1, 2))
print("Total of flowers is:", flowers)
```

Alternatively with a loop it could look like this:

```
women = int(input("Insert number of buyers: "))
flowers = 0
for i in range(1, women+1):
    if i%2 == 1:
        flowers += i
print("Total of flowers is:", flowers)
```

Or look like this using a loop and `range`'s step parameter:

```
women = int(input("Insert number of buyers: "))
flowers = 0
for i in range(1, women+1, 2):
    flowers += i
print("Total of flowers is:", flowers)
```

In future production code, you would go for variant 1 or 2.

Comment: That sounds like a great way for the questioner to advertise that he got the answer to his homework off the internet.

Comment: (I agree that if you wanted to do the computation in the questioner's homework in real code, this would be a prettier way to do it than with a `while` loop, of course.)

Comment: You can spare the `if` when using the `step` argument to range: `range(1, women + 1, 2)`

Comment: While this is ultimately a good answer, it's really not relevant to the person asking the question.

Comment: I added a few alternatives including some with loops and some using the step parameter of `range`.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `for` loop would, to my opinion, be simpler.

```
women = int(input("Insert number of buyers: "))
sum = 0

for i in range(1,women+1):
    if i%2 != 0: # If i is odd
        sum += 1

print("Total of flowers is: " + str(sum))
```

or

```
women = int(input("Insert number of buyers: "))
sum = sum(i for i in range(1,women+1) if i%2 != 0)

print("Total of flowers is: " + str(sum))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Simply Revised code:

```
women = int(input("Insert number of buyers: "));
i = 1;
sum = i;
if women%2==0:
   women=women-1;
while i < women:
   i = i + 2;
   sum = sum + i;
print("Total of flowers is: " + str(sum));
```